# Website shows inescure connection when using www in safari only

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, ssl, https

I have a wordpress site thats on a vps server where it keeps showing insecure site when accessing with [www.mydomain.com](http://www.mydomain.com)
I do have a ssl installed and it works fine on all other browsers but with safari i keep getting that error. My .htaccess file looks like so

```
    # BEGIN rlrssslReallySimpleSSL rsssl_version[2.3.14]
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
# END rlrssslReallySimpleSSL

# BEGIN WordPress
# The directives (lines) between "BEGIN WordPress" and "END WordPress" are
# dynamically generated, and should only be modified via WordPress filters.
# Any changes to the directives between these markers will be overwritten.
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c> 
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.example\.com [NC] 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.com/$1 [L,R=301] 
</IfModule>
```

Where i am trying to redirect anything with a www to just use https://..... but still doesnt  seem to work. Any ideas that can help?
[image]

Comment: Check your site with [SSLLabs](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html) and look out for *chain problems* or similar. If you find this you'll need to fix your setup. Browsers often succeed in working around such setup problems but not always.

Answer (score 0):

The SSL that you bought must be trusted by the browser,Safari in your case, if your browser is too old , the CA (certificate authority) won't be installed in your browse , you can either update your browser to get the latest CAs or buy a new SSL from a CA that is trusted by your old browser  , you can find a list of trusted root certificates by Safari (depending on the version) here https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT209143

An other option, but this is not a good solution if you plan to make your website / webapp public , is to import manually the certificate into your browser to trust it and get the green lock , here is how to import a p12 file into safari https://www.digicert.com/kb/ssl-support/p12-import-export-mac-server.htm , but again this is not a solution for public usage